# Winforms ComboBox User Control Binding

Tags: c#, winforms, data-binding, combobox, user-controls

I have a user control that inherited from Combobox control. I want to bind data in the constructor of the user control. but when I add it to form and run the project it shows duplicated items.

When I add control to my winform its add items in the Designer file of form and when I run project it added again in constructor of user control.

```
public partial class CheckSeriesBox : ComboBox
{
    private static List<string> CheckSeries;

    public CheckSeriesBox()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        CheckSeries = new List<string>();
        SetCheckSeries();

        this.Items.AddRange(CheckSeries.ToArray());
        this.SelectedIndex = 0;
    }

    public static List<string> SetCheckSeries()
    {
        CheckSeries.Add("A");
        CheckSeries.Add("B");
    }
}
```

Comment: Please  put one more line   if(CheckSeries.Count > 0) {  CheckSeries.RemoveAll(); } before calling SetCheckSeries Method

Comment: one more thing instead of creating static variable. Please use public property if it serves your purpose. Because due to static varaible it is possible that some where it might get change

Comment: @AshokRathod When I add control to my winform its add items in the Designer file of form and when I run project it added again in constructor of user control.

Comment: Means your problem is solved ?  then please mark it as solved

Comment: @AshokRathod No it doesn't solved. I can't solve this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/vstudio/en-US/3e35b534-7d3f-4832-8859-b5cb838bd62a/extended-combobox-adds-items-twice

```
public partial class CheckSeriesBox : ComboBox
{
    private static List<string> CheckSeries;

    public CheckSeriesBox()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        CheckSeries = new List<string>();
        SetCheckSeries();

        if (DesignMode)
        {
             this.Items.AddRange(CheckSeries.ToArray());
        }
    }

    public static List<string> SetCheckSeries()
    {
        CheckSeries.Add("A");
        CheckSeries.Add("B");
    }

    protected new bool DesignMode
    {
        get
        {
            if (base.DesignMode)
            {
                return true;
            }
            else
            {
                Control parent = this.Parent;
                while ((parent != null))
                {
                    System.ComponentModel.ISite site = parent.Site;
                    if ((site != null) && site.DesignMode)
                    {
                        return true;
                    }
                    parent = parent.Parent;
                }
                return false;
            }
        }
    }

}
```